# How to customize the first row of every column in HTML?

Tags: css, css-tables

I want to customize first row of every column. I tried many HTML and CSS tricks but it's not working with me.

The attached image will explain further. I am using a table plugin in WordPress so I can't add JavaScript or `id` to one single column.

[image]

Comment: Please show us what you tried (your code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
table > * > tr > td:first-child{
    /* css styles */
}
```

Here `*` is used in place of `thead` and `tbody`.

But sometimes using `*` is expensive for performance.. so, if you care about performance go with this:

```
table > thead > tr > td:first-child, table > tbody > tr > td:first-child{
     /* css styles */
}
```

#### or else

There is a trick which I like to share here which doesn't require `:first-child`

```
table > thead > tr > td + td, table > tbody > tr > td{
    /* normal styles */
}

table > thead > tr > td, table > tbody > tr > td{
    /* first-child styles */
}
```

The above trick worked for me everytime because the the first-child is not a sibling of any other td element :). I mean there is no other element above the first-child element. but I prefer using `:first-child` though.

Answer (score 2):

CSS has a `first-child` pseudo-element that should work for you.  [Here is an article abut it.](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/first-child/) Your CSS should end up something like this:

```
table.mytableid > tbody > tr > td:first-child {
    background: blue;
    color: white;
}
```

`>` is used for elements that must be direct children.

Comment: Mr. Greem and stephen thanks a lot for your support. It works like a magic now